# Pointer pointing to invalid location error in C

Tags: c, pointers, gdb, initialization, memory-address

I'm running a function and I am getting an error at line 10. When debugging on gdb I see ptr is pointing to 0x0. I'm assuming this refers to something about an invalid address location. Why is this and how can I fix the code again. Thank you

```
1  static char *kstrdup(const char *buf)
2  {
3     char *ptr, *ret;
4 
5     ret = ptr = kmalloc(strlen(buf) + 1);
6     if ((ptr = NULL))
7         panic("kmalloc returned NULL");
8 
9     for (; *buf != '\0'; ++ptr, ++buf)
10        *ptr = *buf;
11
12    *ptr = '\0';
13
14    return ret;
15 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
if ((ptr = NULL))
```

as it as an *assignment* and not a *comparision*. If assigns the `NULL` to `ptr` and the result of the assignment is zero which means the condition is `false` and the `if ()` is not entered and `panic()` is not called (which presuambly exits the program). The remaining code then dereferences a `NULL` pointer, which is undefined behaviour.

Change to:

```
if (ptr == NULL) /* or if (!ptr)
```

Some developers prefer putting a `const` value when available on the left-hand side of an equality check so the compiler can assist in detecting this mistake. For example, if you had written:

```
if (NULL = ptr)
```

the compiler would have emitted an error (such as *left operand must be l-value*) and compilation would have failed.

Comment: Or better yet, change it to `if(ptr == NULL)`. Some stupid compilers suppress warnings when they see a double parenthesis. If the compiler wasn't stupid, it would have given a warning for this code.

Comment: It is often wise to write your code with the constant first in conditionals... instead of if( ptr == NULL ) you can write if( NULL == pointer ) -- the advantage to this is that if/when you accidentally leave off that second '=' and turn your conditional into an assignment, the compiler will balk at the attempt to assign a value to a constant. It's an easy way of avoiding subtle runtime errors in your code.

Comment: @KScottPiel, was just updating to include that. I do this regularly but some developers dislike it.

Comment: Thank you! I spent 4 hours on this bug while you spent less than 5 minutes. You're a lifesaver

Comment: Experience is defined as the ability to recognize a mistake when you're making it again... we spent 5 minutes on it because we've done it a hundred times ~grin~

Comment: Upvote removed because of the poor advise to obfuscate the order of parameters. This is _nonsense_, all compilers can warn against assignment inside expressions ever since Turbo C release in 1990. Thus this way of obfuscating programs to dodge this bug has been obsolete for 23 years. The _correct_ way to dodge such bugs is to get a decent compiler with warnings enabled,

Comment: @KScottPiel No it is not wise, that particular "good advise" has been obsolete since the 80s, see my comment above.

Comment: @Lundin, that is how long I have been programming! I was unsure if all compilers, at max warning level, would emit the warning of assignment within a condition. I think nonsense is a bit strong, but you are entitled to your opinion.

Comment: @hmjd Today, most professional programmers use some sort of static analysis tool, in addition to a compiler with all warnings enabled. To use modern tools is wise, to follow code obfuscation rules invented in the 80s, even before ANSI/ISO standardization, is nonsense. But that is of course my own personal opinion.

Answer (score 0):

There is a great tutorial on the difference between assignment and comparison. Its so good that you will subconsciously know when to use assignment and when to use comparison. It is by KN King in his great book http://www.amazon.com/c/knking"> C Programming: A modern approach. Do read it once. BTW `==` falls under `< <= > >= !=`